# $relatedquery batch insert only works with Postgresql and SQL Server

Tags: mysql, typescript, knex.js

I'm new to js. I have this code, where I'm creating a new restaurant. I've seen this is how you insert a relation into a join-table `await newRestaurant.$relatedQuery('tags', trx).relate(tagIds);`

I can't do this with mysql? What is the workaround for this? This is the message I got from postman: `"message": "batch insert only works with Postgresql and SQL Server"`

tags belong to a model class RestaurantTag that has id and name on it, which is on Restaurant model with a many-to-many relation mapping.

```
export const createRestaurant: ExpressHandlerFn = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const {
      name,
      description,
      address,
      cityId,
      priceTier,
      phoneNumber,
      schedule,
      tagIds,
    } = req.body;
    const { thumbnailImage, galleryImages } = req.files as MulterFields;
    const userId = req.session!.id;

    const createRestaurantTransaction = await Restaurant.transaction(async (trx) => {
      let newRestaurant = await Restaurant.query(trx).insertGraphAndFetch({
        name,
        description,
        priceTier,
        address,
        cityId,
        phoneNumber,
        schedule,
      });

      await newRestaurant.$relatedQuery('tags', trx).relate(tagIds);
```

Let me know if I missed some info, any help on this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out I guess,

```
      const promises: Promise<any>[] = [];

      for (const tagId of <number[]>tagIds) {
        promises.push(newRestaurant.$relatedQuery('tags', trx).relate(tagId));
      }

      await Promise.all(promises);
```